# sleep getting hang in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, sleep

I had a cron script running on my Ubuntu PC which periodically checks for disk space. There was a "sleep 5" also used in this script. This system was up for a month, but an issue is encountered. There were multiple instances of cron script running (around thousands) and multiple instances of "sleep".

Crontab entry:

```
* * * * * /root/disk_check_script.sh
```

Content of disk_check_script.sh :

```
#!/bin/sh -x

/home/user/linux/process_health_daemons status

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then

     /home/user/linux/process_health_daemons start

fi

sleep 5


MINIMUM_FREE_SPACE_REQUIRED=50

AVAILABLE_FREE_SPACE=$(df -Ph $HOME | tail -1 | awk '{ print $4}' | awk -F "G" '{ print $1 }')

USED_SPACE=$(df -Ph $HOME | tail -1 | awk '{ print $3}' | awk -F "G" '{ print $1 }')

if [ "$AVAILABLE_FREE_SPACE" -lt "$MINIMUM_FREE_SPACE_REQUIRED" ]; then

        touch /home/user/flag/no_space_left

fi
```

When I killed one of the sleep process, cron script associated with it also completed.

Does sleep hangs often? Is it required to restart the machine to avoid this? Any other method to avoid this.

Comment: Is it possible that you are starting your script more often than it terminates? Post your crontab entry.

Comment: You should definitely post your script, and your crontab entry...

Comment: And a part of the output of `ps -ef`, showing when the commands were started.

Comment: Please post the code, not only the output.

Comment: My guess: The script `/home/user/linux/process_health_daemons start` or `/home/user/linux/process_health_daemons status` was hanging for some reason. Crontab did not know, so it started a new instance every minute. 
When after thousands of minutes something changed for the process_health_daemon, all the hanging processes start running. And all scripts run into the sleep 5.

Comment: @WalterA: No process_health_daemons doesnt get hang. I hope sleep 5 gets hang, as sleep 5 should get over after 5 sec, but its hung